# Spark Read Multiple Parquet Files from a variable

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage

I have a MS SQL table which contains a list of files that are stored within an ADLS gen2 account. All files have the same schema and structure.

I have concatenated the results of the table into a string.

```
mystring = ""
for index, row in files.iterrows():
    mystring += "'"+ row["path"] + "',"

mystring =   mystring[:-1]  
print(mystring)
```

OUTPUT

```
'abfss://[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/08/26/003156/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/08/30/002554/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/09/02/003115/file.parquet'
```

I am now attempting to pass the string using

```
sdf = spark.read.parquet(mystring)
```

however I am getting the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: 'abfss://[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/08/26/003156/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/08/30/002554/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/09/02/003115/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/09/24/003516/file.parquet','abfss:/[file]@[container].dfs.core.windows.net/ARCHIVE/2021/10/07/002659/file.parquet'
```

When I manually copy and past mystring into read.parquet the code executes with no errors.

Maybe I'm going down a rabbit hole but some feedback would be much appreciated

Comment: i'm guessing `mystring` is actually `"'blahblahblah','blehblehbleh'"` and not `'blahblahblah','blehblehbleh'`

Comment: surely if thats the case wont it appear in the error message as "'blahblahblah.... ?

Comment: in any case, how can a string be multiple strings separated by a comma? side note - if `files` is a list of paths, i think you can directly use that in `spark.read.parquet(*files)`

Comment: I've given it a try but the syntax seems incorrect

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve following the below.

```
paths = []

for index,row in files.iterrows():  
paths.append(row["path"])  
  
df = spark.read.parquet(paths)
```

***RESULTS:***

[image]

***NOTE:*** Make sure you have same schema in all the files.